# Count number of comparisons and swap in selection sort in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I need to count the number of comparisons and swaps in the following selection sort algorithm:

```
import random
lista = random.sample(range(0,20), 20):
def selecao(lista):
    for i in range(0, (len(lista)-1)):
        mini = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(lista)):
            if lista[j] < lista[mini]:
               mini = j
        lista[mini], lista[i] = lista[i],lista[mini]

    return lista
print(selecao(lista))
```

how I can account how many coparisons and swaps are made? Swaps are made in this line:

```
lista[mini], lista[i] = lista[i],lista[mini]
```

c1 represents the number of comparisons and c2 the number of swaps.Thanks

Comment: If you need to count the number of executions of a line, just introduce a counter and put its incrementation right above the line you need to count.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. This is just code working on things we can't see and then a requirement. Please give a [mcve]

Comment: This is a Selection sort algorithm. Receive an array as parameter, select the smaler number and get him in the  first position and so on. I need to account for how many comparisons are made and how many swaps are made. This code works for arrays.

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to create a [mcve], and I can see you tried, but you never actually ran this. It has syntax errors and indentation errors. I'll edit your OP, but you really should make sure it runs before you post it. Regarding your question, you obviously know where the comparisons and swaps happen. Have you tried c1 += 1 and c2 += 1 at those spots?

Comment: To count the number of comparisons, I placed c1 within all of the loop repetitions and if's. And for the number of swaps I put c2 inside the second for and outside the if. Result: (25,2) for an array with 25 elements. I Think thi is wrong, very low swaps are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to count how many times you execute a certain line. You count them. Here's an example:

```
swaps = 0
comparaciones = 0
for i in range(19):
    for _ in range(19-i):
        comparaciones += 1
    swaps += 1
print ("swaps {}, comparisons {}".format(swaps, comparaciones))
```

> swaps 19, comparisons 190

Notice that I used descriptive variable names, instead of c1 and c2. Doing so will help you in the future.